# Page level access in Google sites

Tags: google-workspace, wiki

Is there a feature for providing page level access in [Google sites](http://sites.google.com/)?

Comment: I do not understand the question. Could you please reword and be more specific. Maybe a screenshot of what you are trying to do and a link to the documentation on Google sites that will help explain it for us?

Comment: @MrHinsh means that I want some pages to be accesible by authentication only..The ability to allow certain pages to be private (which can only be accessed by Administrators, Collaborators with given email ids etc.) and certain pages to be viewable by the public.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature has [now been released](http://googledocs.blogspot.com/2011/08/better-control-in-google-sites-with.html).

> Only site owners have the ability to enable this feature, which is
>   turned off by default for new and existing sites. To turn on
>   page-level permissions, go to **More Actions > Sharing and
>   Permissions**.
>
> [image]
>
> From there, click **Enable page-level permissions**. Then, in the
>   dialog box, click **Turn on page-level permissions**.
>
> [image]
>
> Once page-level permissions is enabled, you’ll have [three options to
>   choose from](https://sites.google.com/support/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=1387383&topic=1396907):
>
> - allow a page to inherit all of your site-level permissions
> - elect to include future site-level changes to a page
> - prevent a page from inheriting any future changes made at the site-level
>
> [image]
>
> Using page-level permissions should give you greater control over who
>   can edit and access your Google site. To learn more about setting
>   page-level permissions, take a look at our [getting started guide](https://sites.google.com/support/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=1387383&topic=1387643).
>   Let us know what you think in our [support forums](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/sites?hl=en).

Answer (score 1):

As I found from one article that *this feature is not released yet*.

For more information, refer this link: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/sites/thread?tid=0af2865116e1c041&hl=en&start=40